# Seeing message "You can only post once every 90 minutes", but my last question/post was days ago

Tags: bug

Just wrote a new question on SO, but when I tried to post it, I was told

"You can only post once every 90 minutes"

But I last posted around 5 days ago.

Is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible someone on your network or IP did something that triggered a rate limit. If you are using a shared connection like in a dorm, a VPN, or Tor, that might well be the cause.

Comment: Nope, working from home using private router. I'm the only possible developer that would post to SO from this IP.

Comment: Make sure you aren't using your phone 4G network. Sometimes it happens. You think you are running off your WiFi but you are using a public network

Comment: Now this got me concerned that I might have some malware/virus on my computer, but why would it post to SO from this IP. I guess it could also be someone else that somehow connected to my WiFi, but that's unlikely. Is there a way to have a link to the post that was supposedly made from this IP. I'm extremely intrigued now!

Comment: Nope, running off my development PC.

Comment: It looks like many people are assigned to your apparent IP, so I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: Yeah, off the top of my head, I think I count around at least 12 possible permanent users, including ~5 family member's cell phones/tablets, ~3 smart tvs, 2 network drives, 1 plex server, 1 internet security system. But, I'm the only developer working at home.

Comment: Is there a way to have a link to the post that was supposedly made from this IP. I'm extremely intrigued now!

Comment: We can't do that, as it would entail revealing the private information of another user (imagine, purely hypothetically and not related to this, someone posting anonymously on [interpersonal.se] about their roommate).

Comment: Ah, i thought it could only be development posts; in which case, it needn't be private. Last question. Are you completely sure there's an actual post (it exists) made from this IP address? Imagine being told this happened while you were working from your home office? This is quite stressful. It's gotta be an error!

Comment: I painfully waited >90 minutes since I got the error, try to post again, same error. Does someone keep posting to SO from this address? That sounds very unlikely!

Comment: To be clear, at least one of your recent IPs has many, many, many accounts associated with it.  It is possible your ISP is sharing your IP address between multiple customers to reduce the number of IP addresses they need to acquire.

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. But... just tried to post and got same error. It's been almost 2 hours!

Comment: hmm, just went to my phone, that's connected via same wifi, and was able to post question that was still in draft. weird, but i'm glad it's finally posted. thanks!

Comment: It's likely not related that it was the phone. I suspect enough time had passed.

Comment: Since it worked from your phone but not your desktop PC, despite both being connected to the same Wi-Fi, is it possible that your desktop PC is connected to a VPN (e.g., provided by your workplace)?

Comment: I'm an independent contractor, and it's my home office and I'm not using a vpn. Thanks!